# Sending a notification from firebase console initialize Application class when the App is killed

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm sending a push notification from firebase console with a title and text to an Android app that is killed.
The push notification is received well and onMessageReceived listener is not called as expected, but the main application is initialized, this is something that always will happen for some reason, or is initialized for something else that maybe I can avoid?
Because I want to send a message to this app, but I don't want to initialize the Application class because many APIs are called there.

Thanks!

Comment: How do you mean "onMessageReceived listener is not called as expected"? It is not called at all or it is not called as you expect? post some code from your onMessageReceived.

Comment: Hi @adnandann

There are 2 types of notifications:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages

In my case im using notification message, the listener should works just in foreground. 
The things is that this app is killed, so i dont understand why application class is initialized if onMessageReceived will never be called.

Comment: I understand these types... I just tested all possible options and faced the same problem, I think there is no other way. I thought fcm works differently than I think now ... Probably the context is the reason ..
We will wait for someone who better understands this